# How to set S3 bucket Policy on multiple Objects?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

How to set S3 bucket Policy on multiple Objects?

```
Statement allowRestrictedWriteStatement = new Statement(Effect.Allow)
             .withPrincipals(new Principal("12345678910"))
             .withActions(S3Actions.DeleteObject)
             .withResources(new S3ObjectResource(myBucketName, "folder1/folder2"));

     Statement allowRestrictedWriteStatement2 = new Statement(Effect.Deny)
             .withPrincipals(new Principal("12345678910"))
             .withActions(S3Actions.DeleteObject)
             .withResources(new S3ObjectResource(myBucketName, "folder1/folder3"));

     Policy policy = new Policy()
             .withStatements(allowRestrictedWriteStatement,allowRestrictedWriteStatement2);

     AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyyyyy");
     AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
     s3client.setBucketPolicy(myBucketName,policy.toJson());
```

With the help of above code I can set the allow and deny permission on two bucket objects. What if we need to set the allow and deny on the object available on two list i.e., listAllow and listDeny contain 5 objects each and I need to set bucket policy on these objects of lists. Any Suggestion, please?.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution -

```
List<Statement> newlistAllow = new ArrayList <>();
 for (CommonPrefix  objectToDelete:listAllow) {
     Statement allowRestrictedWriteStatement = new Statement(Statement.Effect.Allow)
             .withPrincipals(new Principal("12345678910"))
             .withActions(S3Actions.DeleteObject)
             .withResources(new S3ObjectResource(bucketNameToUse,objectToDelete.toString()));
     newlistAllow.add(allowRestrictedWriteStatement);
 }

 List<Statement> newlistDeny = new ArrayList <>();
 for (CommonPrefix objectToRetain:listDeny) {
     Statement denyRestrictedWriteStatement = new Statement(Statement.Effect.Deny)
             .withPrincipals(new Principal("12345678910"))
             .withActions(S3Actions.DeleteObject)
             .withResources(new S3ObjectResource(bucketNameToUse,objectToRetain.toString()));
     newlistDeny.add(denyRestrictedWriteStatement);
 }

 Policy policyDeny = new Policy();
 policyDeny.setStatements(newlistDeny);
 Policy policyAllow = new Policy();
 policyAllow.setStatements(newlistAllow);

 AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
 AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

 s3client.setBucketPolicy(bucketNameToUse,policyAllow.toJson());
 s3client.setBucketPolicy(bucketNameToUse,policyDeny.toJson());
```